# Submitting app to Apple store "Unable to find info.plist"

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, app-store

When i try to submit my app to the Apple store i get this error!
"Unable to find info.plist"
But the nameapp_info.plist is in the project!!! 
I already send this application to the app store in the past without this error!
I upgraded to xcode 4 and to get my project work fine with the new IDE I had to re-edit my scheme app in automatic.
What I missing??? thanks

Comment: I resolve this error by changing in the project option the device supported!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's expecting a file called "info.plist", whereas your plist file is actually named something different... click on your project file in the Project Navigator, then click your target. Under the Packaging section is a setting for "Info.plist File." Make sure that it is set to the filename that your plist file is actually set to.

Comment: The name is the same!! Is it possible that xcode build the release and not the debug version of my app? How can i change this option?